# I can't install ros at the first step!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow the instruction:
1.on Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu oneiric main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
```

2.Set up my keys:

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

3.`sudo apt-get update`

However ,it doesn't work:

```
Get:75 http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn oneiric-security/restricted Translation-en [978 B]
Get:76 http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn oneiric-security/universe Translation-en [45.9 kB]
Fetched 19.7 MB in 11s (1,657 kB/s)                                            
W: Failed to fetch gzip:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/packages.ros.org_ros_ubuntu_dists_oneiric_main_binary-i386_Packages  Hash Sum mismatch
```

I have try to clean the /var/lib/apt/lists,but it doesn't work.

I installed fuerte several months ago,and this time I even can't install the ros!

This problem have bothered me a month....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58507/i-can%27t-install-ros-at-the-first-step!/) by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2013-03-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-03-19**:
what if you disable the bjtu.edu.cn source from your sources?

**Comment by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on 2013-03-19**:
it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is likely an issue with the mirror you are using.  I suggest trying the main repositories or else contact your mirror administrator.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

to clean the repositories.
Please comment or reply if it worked.

---

Originally posted by [aimc](https://answers.ros.org/users/3966/aimc/) with karma: 216 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bobliao](https://answers.ros.org/users/2976/bobliao/) on 2013-03-19**:
No,I try it ,but it doesn't work , I have also reinstall the ubuntu three times ,but failed